# storing a PILLOW image in same name after editing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, filenames

I want to crop a set of Pillow images and save it with the same name in the same folder, from where it is opened. It is clustered and stored into 4 groups.

I wrote the code as below.

```
for c in range(4):
    for image_file in glob.glob(f"plot_images/{c}/*.jpg"):
        im=Image.open(image_file)
        im = im.convert("RGB")
        im = im.crop(offset)
        im.save(im.filename)
```

It gives me the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9f3d3a38e4e4> in <module>
     15         im = im.crop(offset)
     16         #im.show()
---> 17         im.save(im.filename)
     18         #print(c,end='\r')
     19 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    539             )
    540             return self._category
--> 541         raise AttributeError(name)
    542 
    543     @property

AttributeError: filename
```

I don't understand why the error comes. please help.

Comment: after converting/croping/etc you get new image which don't have `filename`. Use `image_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check `type(im)` in different moments then you should see `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile` after loading but `PIL.Image.Image` after converting which don't have `filename`. Use `image_file` instead of `im.filename`

```
im.save(image_file)
```

---

```
im = Image.open(image_file)
print(type(im)) # <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>

im = im.convert("RGB")
print(type(im)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

im = im.crop(offset)    
print(type(im)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

im.save(image_file)
```